# Jquery animation entering page

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, load

I'm a newbie with jquery and I'm trying to code a very simple animation. I've already coded the div movement but I would like the animation to start automatically when entering the page without clicking or hovering anything.

So this is the code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").hover(function(){
$("#div02").animate({left:'150px'});
});
$("p").hover(function(){
$("#div01").animate({left:'180px'});
});
});
</script> 

<style>
#div02{background:url(norahalf.png) no-repeat; background-  size:contain;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;}

#div01{background:url(rinohalf.png) no-repeat; background-size:contain;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute; left:500px}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>something something dark side</p>
<div id="div02"><img src="pixeltransp.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="rino" title="rino"></div>
<div id="div01"><img src="pixeltransp.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="nora" title="nora"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Nora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not having the `animate` function executed after hovering the paragraph, then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div02").animate({left:'150px'});
    $("#div01").animate({left:'180px'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start automatically you just need to trigger `mouseover` event on page load:

```
$(function() {
    $("p").hover(function() {
        $("#div02").animate({ left: '150px' });
        $("#div01").animate({ left: '180px' });
    })
    .trigger('mouseover');
});
```

I'm not sure if you still need this `p` hover event at all though.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rDMGC/